# Clustering longitudinal data (geohash over 24h)

Tags: time-series, clustering, python

as the title says I would like to run a clustering algorithm (eventually evolving it in some semi-supervised model) on this dataset that describes the position of a person throughout the day. What I do right now is map the coordinates to geohashes (to obtain a single value) and plotting these values I see that there are strong patterns (commuters, people that stay at home the whole day, people that travels to another city and a minority of people that do multiple trips in a day). I would like to learn a clustering model to split them into categories to better explore them and eventually classify them.

I've seen an algorithm called kmlShape that looks very promising but it's implemented only in R and I've never used it so before tackling a new tech stack, I would like to know if there are good alternatives that I can work with using python.

Some additional information: the learning algorithm should be able to clusterize indipendently from the magnitude of the trends and be invariant in respect of time (a commuter that leaves at 6 am should be clusterized together with a commuter that leaves at 9 am). The series are all in a 0-24 time interval.

Comment: You may want to take a look at TsLearn [HERE](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)